# If the year is x or y, skip every other row, otherwise, just go to the next line of code in the pipe

Tags: r, if-statement, conditional-statements, pipe, subset

I have seven years of temperature data recorded every hour for about 9 weeks.
However two of the years have recorded every half an hour.
For those two years, I only want to use every other line, hence hourly data.

I have 112 nests over the seven years. There are 188550 rows of data...
The first few lines of original data:

```
> head(TempData)
# A tibble: 6 x 6
  Beach  Nest  Year Datetime             Temp NestID  
  <chr> <dbl> <dbl> <dttm>              <dbl> <fct>   
1 LB        1  2014 2014-01-12 09:00:00  27.2 LB1_2014
2 LB        1  2014 2014-01-12 10:00:00  27.2 LB1_2014
3 LB        1  2014 2014-01-12 11:00:00  27.2 LB1_2014
4 LB        1  2014 2014-01-12 12:00:00  27.2 LB1_2014
5 LB        1  2014 2014-01-12 13:00:00  27.2 LB1_2014
6 LB        1  2014 2014-01-12 14:00:00  27.1 LB1_2014
```

Using an if / else statement gives the following warning:

`Warning message:In if (.$Year == 2015 | .$Year == 2016) { :  the condition has length > 1 and only the first element will be used`

So I have tried using an ifelse statement, but now I get an error message:

`Error in ifelse(., .$Year == 2015 | .$Year == 2016, subset(row_number()%%2 ==  :   (list) object cannot be coerced to type 'logical'`

Can anyone offer any other suggestions/ help?

This the beginning of my code:

```
  FloodedNestsIncSub = group_by (TempData, NestID, Nest, Year) %>%
  ifelse (.$Year == 2015 | .$Year == 2016, subset(row_number() %% 2 == 1) ) %>%
  mutate(TempDrop = Temp - lag(Temp, n=1, default = first(Temp))) %>%
  mutate(Flooded = TempDrop < -0.45)
```

If I add a comma after "subset(row_number() %% 2 == 1", and leave it blank - the else is simply to go to the next line,
I get a different error:

```
Error in ifelse(., .$Year == 2015 | .$Year == 2016, subset(row_number()%%2 ==  : 
  unused argument (alist())
```

I need code for
If the year is 2015 or 2016, skip every other row, then go to the next line of code;
else, just go to the next line of code ...

Comment: sorry, a bit hard to say without looking at the data, but could you not create a new column where you have an indicator of whether that row should be included or not. Then you could filter the data based on that indicator.

Comment: Hey! I shall add some data for clarity. There are over a thousand rows for each of 112 nests. About 15 nests in the two years I need every other row for. I shall give it some thought ... Thank you!

Comment: If you want whole hours only, can't you just filter where minutes == 00 in `Datetime`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If measurements are every 30 minutes you can just filter the once at 30 minutes out.
This will remove half.
This can be done like this:

```
TempData %>% 
    # Only keep whole hours
    dplyr::filter(lubridate::minute(Datetime) == 0) %>%
    # Rest of pipe
    dplyr::mutate(
        TempDrop = Temp - dplyr::lag(Temp, n=1, default = first(Temp)),
        Flooded = TempDrop < -0.45
    )
```

Comment: Thank you so much!! Ages ago I thought using Datetime would work, but couldn't work out how. So much appreciated! Thanks again!